# Divide integer number into 3 parts using php

Tags: php, integer, divide

I need to divide an integer value into 3 parts using php

for eg:  I have a value 9     the answer is like 3 + 3 + 3
         if i have value 10   the ans like 3 + 3 + 4 or something like that

Comment: what if you a value of `2`?

Comment: @491243 may be `0+1+1`

Comment: If value is 7? `3+3+1`? So always include `3`? Explain more

Comment: 10 = 2+4+4 , 10 = 3+5+2,10=1+8+1 ....so on.. which three digits you want ??

Comment: "or something like that" so "fish, cat, frog" would be acceptiable then?

Comment: What about 1 + 1 + ($i-2) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a modulus function.

```
<?php
    $yourInt=10;
    $remainder=$yourInt % 3;
    $third=floor($yourInt/3);
    $lastBit=$third+$remainder;

    echo "The numbers are $third + $third + $lastBit.";
?>
```

Output:

```
The numbers are 3 + 3 + 4.
```

Comment: Could have thought of the modulo-operator :D

Comment: No problems, if you are happy with it, it's polite to Accept the answer, so that other folks don't spend time answering something you are already happy with :)

Comment: @Fluffeh I don't think your answer is working. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Simon_eQ No just rolled the dice. However, I did fix a few typos upon testing and how now updated :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a value that is >= 3 you can do the following:

```
$number = 10;
$number1and2 = floor($number/3);
$number3 = $number - (2*$number1and2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 11; 

$d = [$num/3,$num/3,$num/3];

$round = array_map('round', $d);    
list($first, $second, $third) = $round;
$round = (is_float($num/3)) ? $num-(round($num/3)*3) : 0;

echo $first.' '.$second.' '.($third += (is_float($num/3)) ? $num-(round($num/3)*3) : 0);
```